# Можно ли встроить cron на сайт?

Tags: cron, php

Проблема такая.

1. Нужен периодический запуск php скрипта.
2. Крон есть у хостера, но не работает, причем техподдержка сама не знает, как с ним управляться и к журналу ошибок не пускает. То есть даже непонятно, где запрос ошибочен.

Можно ли встроить утилиту в обход хостера, т.е. на сам сайт?

Comment: Если результаты периодической обработки будут использоваться только на сайте, то можно сделать свой внутренний планировщик встроенный в php-скрипт. Когда пользователь грузит страницу, php-функция проверяет необходимость запуска задачи, и, если эта самая необходимость есть, то запускает.

Comment: Не самый лучший костыль, но явно лучше предложения ставить крон на удалённый компьютер.  
По теме: долбите тп, пусть разбираются с кроном. Это их обязанность.

Comment: @metazet да, если нужна строгая периодичность запуска задач - вариант не подойдет. Зависишь от активности посещений сайта. Но, если задача типа кеширования рсс-лент, то то что нужно. Лента будет читаться раз в определенный интервал времени, и только в том случае если за это время был хотябы один посетитель.

Comment: @KiTE полностью с Вами согласен. Но все же, если делать - то как надо. Я не сторонник костылей - есть печальные опыты...

Comment: @metazet, проблема, конечно, их, но я состою в переписке с тп уже неделю, а воз и ныне там. Предложенный вариант не подходит, ибо, скрипт должен запускаться в определенное время.

Comment: Если не смертельное действие - то как предложил товарищ @KiTE, при заходе на сайт проверяйте серверное время и запускайте скрипт, если оно примерно подходит. Печально, когда такая тугая тп :(

Comment: @metazet, увы, скрипт должен запускаться каждую минуту или на крайний случай, каждые пять минут. Я же не могу торчать там пожизненно.
Да уж, к сожалению, хостинговую компанию не я выбирала.

Comment: А как тогда такой вариант(не силен в php, главное идея):  
пишется скрипт, который запускается вручную на сервере. В скрипте - бесконечный цикл с проверкой на серверное время. Если секунды == 0(ну или как там, я хз), то запуск необходимого скрипта, иначе пропустить.

Comment: @metazet, идея богатая, но я доругалась с тп. Урра!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Крон - это отдельная программа на сервере, но можно вызывать пхп скрипты с удалённого компьютера установив крон на него. Просто тогда нужно в крон добавить строчку :

```
/usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/cron.php >/dev/null (Для линукса)
```

И поставить необходимую переодичность